# about minimal prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with minimal prime ideals $p_1,\ldots, p_n$ and $D=R/{p_1}\times \cdots \times R/p_n$. Please find an element $x\in R$ such that $\mathrm{ann}_D(x+p_1,\ldots,x+p_n)=\mathrm{ann}_D(1+p_1,p_2,\ldots,p_n)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Show that $p_2p_3 \dotsb p_n$ is not contained in $p_1$ and take some element according to this fact.